# Using a flexbox in a bootstrap container gives me scrollbars in the wrong places

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar, containers

I want my page to have a flexbox layout, where the header and the footer stay in the same place, but the content fills the rest of the screen. However, because of the way my page is set up, I need to use a container in the main content area of my code. This gives me the problem of a scroll bar that is not on the side of the page where it should be, rather it is at the edge of the container.

Can anyone help me either get the scroll bar to where it is supposed to be or tell me why I can't do it the way I am doing it, and give me a viable work-around?

Here is the original working example without bootstrap:

https://jsfiddle.net/SuperMelons/n2s9xrt0/

HTML:

```
<div class="mybox">
  <div class="myrow myheader">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="myrow mycontent">
    <p>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="myrow myfooter">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.mybox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.mybox .myrow {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.mybox .myrow.myheader {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.mybox .myrow.mycontent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.mybox .myrow.myfooter {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}
```

Here is the example that is not working because of the bootstrap container:

https://jsfiddle.net/SuperMelons/2L5cbt8m/2/

HTML with Bootstrap:

```
<div class="mybox">
  <div class="myrow myheader">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class="myrow mycontent container">
    <p>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
      content<br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="myrow myfooter">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible with CSS. The broswer adds scrollbars where there is overflow. Since the page doesn't overflow, you don't get scrollbars on the page. JS might do something.

Comment: A simple fix is to set `width: 100%` in your `mybox` rule, which also avoids the fixed width's _bootstraps_ media query applies at certain screen sizes https://jsfiddle.net/2L5cbt8m/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want somethink like this ?

https://jsfiddle.net/uykf3Lp8/2/

```
<div class="myrow mycontent">
    <div class="container">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To only answer with a code and no explanation of what you did and why it works, is not a good answer. ... and no need for the extra wrapper you added as you can see in my answer